# Capturing groups in string using preg_match

Tags: php, regex, codeigniter

I got in trouble parsing a text file in codeigniter, for each line in file I need to capture groups data...the data are:
- progressive number
- operator
- manufacturer
- model
- registration
- type

Here you are an example of the file lines

```
 8  SIRIO S.P.A.                                             BOMBARDIER INC.                                       BD-100-1A10             I-FORZ              STANDARD

 9  ESERCENTE PRIVATO                                        PIAGGIO AERO INDUSTRIES S.P.A.                        P.180 AVANTI II         I-FXRJ              SPECIALE/STANDARD

10  MIGNINI & PETRINI S.P.A.                                 ROBINSON HELICOPTER COMPANY                           R44 II                  I-HIKE              SPECIALE/STANDARD

11  MIGNINI & PETRINI S.P.A.                                 ROBINSON HELICOPTER COMPANY                           R44 II                  I-HIKE              STANDARD

12  BLUE PANORAMA AIRLINES S.P.A.                            THE BOEING COMPANY                                    737-86N                 I-LCFC              STANDARD
```

To parse each line I'm using the following code:

```
if ($fh = fopen($filePath, 'r')) {
    while (!feof($fh)) {
        $line = trim(fgets($fh));

        if(preg_match('/^(\d{1,})\s+(\w{1,})\s+(\w{1,})\s+(\w{1,})\s+(\w{1,})\s+(\w{1,})$/i', $line, $matches))
       {
             $regs[] = array(
             'Operator'     => $matches[1],
             'Manufacturer' => $matches[2],
             'Model'        => $matches[3],
             'Registration' => $matches[4],
             'Type'         => $matches[5]
             );
             $this->data['error'] = FALSE;
        }
    }
    fclose($fh);
 }
```

The code above doesn't work...I think because some groups of data are composed by more then one words...for example "SIRIO S.P.A."
Any hint to fix this?
Thanks a lot for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not use `\w` for capturing the data as some of the characters in your text like `&`, `.`, `-` and `/` are not part of word characters. Moreover some of them are space separated, so you should replace `\w{1,}` with `\S+(?: \S+)*` which will capture your text properly into groups you have made.

Try changing your regex to this and it should work,

```
^\s*(\d+)\s+(\S+(?: \S+)*)\s+(\S+(?: \S+)*)\s+(\S+(?: \S+)*)\s+(\S+(?: \S+)*)\s+(\S+(?: \S+)*)$
```

**[Check this demo](https://regex101.com/r/fxkQel/1/)**

**Explanation of what `\S+(?: \S+)*` does in above regex.**

- `\S+` - `\S` is opposite of `\s` meaning it matches any non-whitespace (won't match a space or tab or newline or vertical space or horizontal space and in general any whitespace) character. Hence `\S+` matches one or more visible characters
- `(?: \S+)*` - Here `?:` is only for turning a group as non-capture group and following it has a space and `\S+` and all of it is enclosed in parenthesis with `*` quantifier. So this means match a space followed by one or more non-whitespace character and whole of it zero or more times as `*` quantifier is used.

So `\S+(?: \S+)` will match `abc` or `abc xyz` or `abc pqr xyz` and so on but the moment more than one space appears, the match stops as there is only a single space present in the regex before `\S+`

Hope my explanation is clear. If still any doubt, please feel free to ask.

Comment: Really appreciated Silvanasa, thanks a lot...I have lot to learn about regex. Could you explain a bit more about this code?: (\S+(?: \S+)*)

Comment: @Federico: Added explanation :)